# How do I play videos in wpf media player?

Tags: c#, wpf

I developed a media player in wpf but it's not playing. Loading is ok, but video is not playing. After opening the video file, video is not playing. By using play button also it's not playing. I dont know where the problem is?

This is my .cs file code:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaElement1.Play();//play button code

        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaElement1.Pause();//pause button code
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaElement1.Stop(); //stop button code
        }

        private void mediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            slider1.Maximum = mediaElement1.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
            slider1.IsEnabled = mediaElement1.IsLoaded;

            slidervolume.IsEnabled = mediaElement1.IsLoaded;

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void file_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

//opening video file into our media element
            OpenFileDialog ofd;
            ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.AddExtension = true;
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.*";
            ofd.Filter = "media (*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.ShowDialog();

            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName);
            mediaElement1.Play();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: which kind of media files are you trying to play. I believe only *.wmv can be played by the mediaelement... or media player compatibility

Comment: i want to play all types of media files

Comment: Hello check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20478/A-simple-WPF-media-player-with-media-item-list

Answer (score 2):

You have to set media element load behavior to manual so that you can manually pause, stop, and play the media element. without setting it to manual you can not deal with this operation such as pause, play and stop.

the following line will work for you.

```
 mediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
 mediaElement1.Play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the format of your video and your installed codec.

And check this  too : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163455.aspx#S1

From Wikipedia : WPF supports the video formats WMV, MPEG and some AVI files by default, but since it has Windows Media Player running beneath, WPF can use all the codecs installed for it.

Try with a basic WMV File (mpeg 2).

Comment: The link to MSDN is dead.